# Qt сигналы слоты

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь соединить два объекта путем сигнально-слотового метода, но в итоге выдает ошибки такого рода:

```
connect( core, SIGNAL(cls()), tcpSender, SLOT(clearMap()) );
```

Ошибка:

> no matching function for call to 'projectname::connect(ccore*&, const char*, tcpconnect*&, const char*)'

- `cls()` обычный сигнал.
- `clearMap()` обычный слот без параметров.

---

```
connect( hdlcHandler, SIGNAL(sendObject(structura)), core, SLOT(receiveObject(structura)) );
```

Ошибка:

> no matching function for call to 'projectname::connect(hdlc*&, const char*, core*&, const char*)'

- сигнал - `sendObject(mapObject);`
- слот - `void receiveObject(mapObject obj);`

```
 struct structura
    {
    int num1;
    float num2;
    float num3;
    QString str;
    float num4;
    float num5;
    float num6;
    float num7;
    float num8;
    float num9;};
```

Comment: В каком контексте вызывается connect? Если не в контексте класса-наследника `QObject`, то можете использовать `QObject::connect(...)`

Comment: Оба объекта принадлежат классам-наследникам QObject

Comment: @Croessmah имел в виду, унаследован ли от `QObject` `projectname`. Ведь именно у него вы вызываете метод `connect()`.

Comment: Наследник от QMainWindow. Имеет макроопределение Q_OBJECT

Comment: Что такое `core` и `tcpSender`?

Comment: Как правильно заметил  Croessmah, вы вызываете connect  из функции, которая не является членом класса-наследника QObject. используете Qobject::connect(...), или hdlcHandler->connect(... ).

Comment: connect вызываю из метода класса наследника QMainWindow

Answer (score 1):

Если `core` и `tcpSender` не `Qobject` указатели , то в `connect`  передайте `Qobject` указатели. А если они обьекты классов, унаследованные от Qobject, то нужно передать их адреса, и функция должна быть в области видимости  `Qobject`

```
Qobject::connect( &hdlcHandler, SIGNAL(sendObject(structura)),
                &core, SLOT(receiveObject(structura)) );
```

Comment: Судя по сообщению об ошибке ( 'projectname::connect(hdlc*&, const char*, core*&, const char*) ) это указатели.